# processor architecture amd64 or arm64?

Tags: debian

I was going through Debian's official website where they had different options for different processor architectures such as amd64,arm64,i386 and so on.

I have Intel Xeon processor and I am currently using windows 64 bit. So which option should i choose? amd64 or arm64?

Answer (score 1):

PCs these days, including yours, are nearly always based on x86-64, AKA AMD64. The ARM family is best known for its use in smartphones, tablets, and other lightweight computers.